# How to get the mouse pointer where the input caret is?

Tags: xorg, mouse, cursor

I am running an Arch Linux system with `i3` window manager.

Let's say I am typing on a GUI editor and I want to insert text with the middle click button of the mouse exactly where I am typing. The idea is after pressing the keybinding the pointer will be place at the input caret and then I can just click the middle button to paste the text.

I know that `xdotool` can get the coordinates of the pointer (mouse), but what I want is to **get the coordinates of the text input caret**, so then I can use `xdotool` to put that same coordinates for the mouse pointer.

Comment: I believe the term you might be looking for is "text input caret". I don't have a ready answer but maybe that'll help you find one. Note that it wouldn't be as simple as you think *in the general case*: consider partly covered focused windows, for example.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKjörling, I changed the question to be more precise. I think it will be difficult for xorg to get the info from the application window to let it know where the input caret is.

Comment: You might also be interested in SHIFT + INSERT. This is the equivalent of mouse middle click.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think this is possible in general: as far as X is concerned, the input caret may be just some differently-colored pixels. Is there a specific application you're interested in?

Comment: @Gilles Not any specific application. As I am using keyboard shortcuts to move the pointer around (keynav and xdotool) I just wanted a quick way to bring the pointer where the input caret is.

Comment: In which editor(s) would you like to do it ?

Comment: @AntoineLecaille: Gvim Editor